# Unable to provision container group in a particular subnet in Azure

Tags: azure, containers

I have 2 container images I would like to deploy (https://hub.docker.com/r/neotys/neoload-controller and https://hub.docker.com/r/neotys/neoload-loadgenerator).  I would like to deploy them into an existing subnet so that they can access resources on our internal network.  However, when I attempt to, I get a resource error:

> {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/$CONTAINER_GROUP","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InaccessibleNetworkResource","message":"The client '$CLIENT_ID' with object id '$CLIENT_ID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/providers/read' over scope '/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Network' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}]}}

I created the subnet within the desired resource group, so I should have permissions.  I can see it in Azure portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) client does not have permission to read the resource group. This can happen for a few reasons:

- The client does not have the necessary permissions on the resource group.
- The client's credentials have expired.
- There is a problem with the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) service.

Verify below points suggested by MS for [DeploymentFailed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/common-deployment-errors#:%7E:text=DeploymentFailed,Find%20error%20code) error message and also verify your details
with `az account show` and upgrade to latest if necessary using `az upgrade`
[image]

check the permissions for the user or role that the client is using to access the resource group.
and finally, if required, create a fresh service principal and grant it the necessary permissions on the resource group

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name neotys-service-principal
```

and get the application ID and client secret for the service principal
output:
[image]

Assign this service principal the Reader role on the resource group using

```
az role assignment create --assignee neotys-service-principal --role Reader --scope /subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP
```

and deploy the container groups using

```
az container group create --name neotys-controller --image neotys/neoload-controller --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --subnet $SUBNET --service-principal-id $APPLICATION_ID --client-secret $CLIENT_SECRET az container group create --name neotys-loadgenerator --image neotys/neoload-loadgenerator --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --subnet $SUBNET --service-principal-id $APPLICATION_ID --client-secret $CLIENT_SECRET
```

Once the container groups have been deployed, you should be able to access them from your internal network.

Reference documents:
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/common-deployment-errors)
[Deployment failed error checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/find-error-code?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: I had to request that permission be granted through our corporate processes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. But, I made a mistake in my deploy script. I am deploying container group using a YAML file, a Resource Manager template. I gave NSG detail instead of subnet, which lead me to the error. After correcting it started working fine.

```
  subnetIds:
   - id: /subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupId/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$virtualNetworkName/subnets/$subnetName
     name: $subnetName
```